# Retrieving a doc from a website by httpwebrequest, does return no query

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

There is public website where i want to retrieve one document programmatically, doing it by browser is working perfectly but doing it by code returns "NO Query".

Could anyone check it out, what am i doing wrong, honestly im stuck on it few days ...

Here is the code:

```
string fileUrl = @"http://docsonline.wto.org/imrd/directdoc.asp?DDFDocuments/t/G\SPS\NALB149.doc";
            Uri uri = new Uri(fileUrl);

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

            using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {

                using (Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (responseStream != null)
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                            int bytesRead;
                            while ((bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                            {
                                memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            }
                            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                            string fileName = fileUrl.Substring(fileUrl.LastIndexOf("/") + 1, fileUrl.Length - fileUrl.LastIndexOf("/") - 1).Replace(@"\", "_");

                            using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(@"C:\temp\" + fileName, (int)memoryStream.Length))
                            {
                                // Fill the bytes[] array with the stream data
                                byte[] bytesInStream = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
                                memoryStream.Read(bytesInStream, 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);

                                // Use FileStream object to write to the specified file
                                fileStream.Write(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

As you can see there is a link to a file which i want to retrieve, could anyone try it out?

Maybe will have more luck than me ...

Waiting for response

Comment: The link redirects to a login page.

Comment: @RichardDeeming, it's not redirecting me that I can tell. Chrome immediately start the download for me.

Comment: Then you're probably signed in to the site in Chrome. Try with Fiddler: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: @RichardDeeming, prior to reading this question, I've never even visited the site (or knew it existed). I'm not signed in. Strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, there's two problems here:

1. You need a cookie container for the request:

   ```
   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
   request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
   ```
2. Your path contains backslashes, which are escaped by the `System.Uri` class. As a result, the request is made for `directdoc.asp?DDFDocuments/t/G%5CSPS%5CNALB149.doc`, which redirects to a 404 error.

To fix #2, you need to pass the `dontEscape` parameter to [the `Uri` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zh9wcb3.aspx):

```
Uri uri = new Uri(fileUrl, true);
```

This constructor has been marked as obsolete since .NET 2.0, but it still works.

With these changes in place, you should be able to download the document successfully.

Comment: Oh man thank you very much, i was stuck on this problem for a few days, and i didn't know how it could happen! Yesterday ofc before reading your answser I noticed that the get URL was already wrong with \ replaced by %5C, but i didn't know exactly how to fix it. Btw is there a way not to used thi obsolete uri constructor, but stil have the sae effect because basically requst doesn't require uir but string is also ok, but i suppose it will be changed also....

Comment: @Alnedru: Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to make this request without using the obsolete constructor. The `WebRequest.Create(string)` method effectively calls `Create(new Uri(requestUriString))`, which will have the same problem.